# Counterexamples: Minimax but not efficient, efficient but not minimax

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, asymptotics, efficiency, minimax

Are there examples of estimators that are minimax, but not efficient? Perhaps, to be more concrete, any of the following:

1. (strong) Estimator sequence for each $n$ that is minimax but does not match the Cramer-Rao lower bound for any $n$
2. (in-between) Estimator sequence for each $n$ that is minimax but does not match the Cramer-Rao lower bound asymptotically ($n\to\infty$)
3. (weak) Estimator sequence that is asymptotically minimax but does not match the Cramer-Rao lower bound asymptotically ($n\to\infty$)
4. Converses: Estimator sequence for each $n$ that matches the Cramer-Rao lower bound for each $n$, but is not minimax for any $n$ (or asymptotically)

Comment: What do you mean by "minimax optimal"?

Comment: Is there more than one usage of this term? I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_estimator

Comment: Ah ha! I see what you mean. Fair enough, sorry for the confusion. You are right that "minimax estimator" is the correct formal terminology.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 4. That Wikipedia link has the example
$$\hat\delta^M= \frac{x+0.5\sqrt{n}}{n+\sqrt{n}}$$
for estimating $\theta$ in $Bin(n,\theta)$. It's not finite-sample efficient because that's one of the models where the MLE, $x/n$, *is* finite-sample efficient.

2. The local asymptotic minimax theorem says that an asymptotically efficient estimator is *locally* asymptotically minimax (over neighbourhoods of size $n^{-1/2}$) for any bowl-shaped loss function, so if there's a counterexample here I think it would have to be a bit pathological.

Comment: I think you may have answered as I was editing my question: I *believe* your answer should now read "1 and 4" and 3 instead of 2. Can you please confirm/edit your answer before I accept. Good answer, btw, and my apologies for the confusion.